# How can I create my own exception?

Tags: c#, exception

This is the skeleton of the code I have:

```
if(CheckForSomething())
{
    try
    {
        //do something
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        LogException(ex, item.server);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogException(ex, item.server);
    }
}
else
{
    string error = "Some error";
    //want to call LogException with error as argument
}

private static void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    //write ex to one log file
    // write ex.message to another log file
}
```

How can I call LogException method from the else block? I tried casting string as exception and creating an exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
LogException(new Exception("some error"));
```

Comment: Though you ought to be using a specific exception rather than the generic one.

Comment: waiting for the time limit to expire. I can't accept for another 3min.

Comment: @xbonez: While this does answer the question and will work for you i really suggest that you consider some of the other answers like Steve Townsend's and Profeten's. This answer is a hack that will allow you to do something that makes little sense. Honestly, if i was doing code review and saw something like this implemented, i would lose it.

Comment: @Paul: I did end up writing an overload for the method that handles strings specifically.

Answer (score 9):

A better question imo is not how but why you would want to do this?  Why not define two `LogError` overloads, one that takes an `Exception` and another that takes a `string`.

```
private static void LogError(Exception ex)
{
    // write ex to one log file
    // write ex.message to another log file
}

private static void LogError(string error)
{
    //nothing to write to exception-specific log file
    // write error info to another log file
}
```

It's not really advisable to generate your own `Exception` instance just for logging like this.

Comment: +1 for truth.  Don't just answer a bad practice, encourage a good one.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered factoring the `// write ex.message to another log file` behavior into a separate function and calling that with your desired string?

```
    if(CheckForSomething())
    {
        try
        {
            // do something
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) // Never do this.  Do you know how to handle an OutOfMemoryException?
        {
            LogException(ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string error = "Some error";
        LogMessage(error);
    }

private static void LogException(Exception ex)
{
    // write ex to one log file
    LogMessage(ex.Message);
}

private static void LogMessage(string message)
{
    // write message to another log file
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also make you own exception class like this:

```
public class LogException: Exception
        {

            public LogException() : base()
            {
            }

            public LogException(string message) : base(message)
            {

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Exception e = new Exception(error);      
LogException ee = new LogException (Exception e);
    throw ee;
```

Put this in the else block

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like previously mentioned

```
LogException(new Exception("some error"));
```

But it might be better to create your own exception class:

```
class MyException : Exception 
{
    //...
}
```

then

```
LogException(new MyException());
```

Answer (score 0):

Some good solutions so far.  You don't want to create a custom exception just for logging someone else will have a WTF? moment reading your code.

The alternative is to just extract the message from exception for the log.... something like

```
if(CheckForSomething())
{
    try
    {
        // do something
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        LogMessage(ex.Message);
    }

}
else
{
    LogMessage("Some Error!");
}
private static void LogMessage(string message)
{
  //write message to log
}
```

Creating an exception for the sole purpose of passing it into a format handled by a method is a hack.  It breaks the implicit understanding among programmers as to what exceptions are and what they are used for.